# How to Back Ground Color

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying assert back ground color this is HTML Template

```
<td style="font:12px arial,sans-serif;background-color: #959595; color:white;"></td>
```

I want value of Background , I tries this

```
String headerCalled = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='cheap3436@mailinator.com']/following-sibling::td[1]")).getCssValue("background-color").toString();
       System.out.println(headerCalled);
       assertEquals(headerCalled,"rgb(255,87,80,1)");
```

It return me 'transparent' as out put ,.

Where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Point it as **important**

.td{background-color: #959595 !important;}

Comment: I did not get It can you please modify my script so that i can get it